# @wrapt decorators and monkey patching

Tags: python, monkeypatching, wrapt

#### @wrapt conditional monkey patching with decorators

[Wrapt](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt) has two feature

- best practice for decorators
- monkey patching

I'm doing both to be able to conditionally change method called.  I've provided an example which is based on pandas version.  While this works,  I have resorted to barebones monkey patching and not using wrapt capability.   How can wrapt be used to monkey patch the alternate method?

```
import pandas as pd
import wrapt, inspect
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
def alt_impl(alt_fn, cond):
    @wrapt.decorator
    def wrapper(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
        nonlocal alt_fn
        if cond():
            # @staticmethod and @classmethod need to navigate to actual function
            if not inspect.isfunction(alt_fn):
                alt_fn = alt_fn.__func__
            # class instance methods need to be bound to class instance
            if instance is not None:
                alt_fn = alt_fn.__get__(instance, instance.__class__)
            return alt_fn(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Example usage

```
class alt_impl_example():
    def upgraded_pandas(self, args):
        print(f"upgraded {pd.__version__}") 

    @alt_impl(upgraded_pandas, lambda: StrictVersion(pd.__version__) >= StrictVersion("1.0.0")) 
    def pandas(self, args): 
        print(pd.__version__) 

t = alt_impl_example()
t.pandas({})
```

Comment: Why not use the ``enabled`` option to ``@wrapt.decorator``. It provides support for conditional application of decorators at time of import, rather than at time of execution, which would seem to satisfy your requirement. See https://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorators.html#enabling-disabling-decorators